# Show that $\lim |x|^y=1$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} |x|^y=1$ .

I evaluated $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} |x|^y= 1$ . Now I have to show for any $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $1-\epsilon<|x|^y<1+\epsilon\; \forall(x,y)[\not=(0,0)]$ satisfying $|x|<\delta,|y|<\delta$.

But I'm unable to find a suitable $\delta$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Please help. Tell me how to define  $\delta$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is showing the limit is 1. But does not providing step by step solution.

Comment: As stated the two-variable limit isn't true: Let $\alpha>0$ be real. If we approach the origin along $x = e^{-\alpha/t^2}$ and $y = t^2$, then $|x|^{y} = e^{-\alpha}$, which is not $1$. The iterated one-variable limit is not the same thing; if that's what's meant could you please edit?

Comment: I know that existence of iterated limit doesn't guarantee existence of double limit. But if both exist they must be equal. Since Wolfram alpha showed the double limit is 1, I thought it exists and wanted to know how to prove that. Now you have showed the double limit does not exist. Well done.

Comment: When $x\to 0$ first, there is no limit.  For $y\gt 0$, limit $=0$.  For $y\lt 0$, limit $=\infty$.  For $y=0$, limit $=1$..

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang . The counter-example I thought of is the pair of sequences $(x_n,y_n)=(e^{-n},1/n)$ and $(x'_n,y'_n)=(1/n,1/n)$ for $n\in\Bbb N.$